# os x lion: git can't find libcrypto.so.0.9.7

Tags: macos, git, ssh, osx-lion

### Background:

I've just replaced my hard drive, and done a fresh install of Lion. I installed git from source and `make test` seemed fine. SSH keys are loaded and I can ssh into the remote box without problem.

### Problem:

I get the following error when trying to pull over ssh when ***using scp style syntax***:

```
$ git pull origin master
git-upload-pack: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.0.9.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My .git/config for origin looks like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = me@example.com:some_repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

**If I change the url to `ssh://me@example.com/path/to/some/repo.git` it works fine.**

I recognize that I could just change all my urls to that format, but I'd rather have a system that works correctly without having to work around setup issues every time.

I was able to push and pull to this repo just fine before reinstalling lion, and I still can with the different syntax. I suspect I symlinked something to work around this on the old hard drive way back in the snow-leopard days, but I'm having a hell of a time googling what it was. I found one post that suggested the problem was a missing library server-side and the error message was misleading, but this can't be the case because it worked just fine on the old hard-drive, and it works just fine with the ssh:// syntax

Anyone know how to address this?

Comment: The shared library: `/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib` should be used on OSX. A symlink might work - but it's strange the build hasn't hard-coded the correct shlib extension.

Comment: Did you figure out what was causing this?

Comment: Alas, I did not. My system magically fixed itself (I suspect during a restart) so I was unable to continue exploring the failure :/ I'm glad it's fixed but annoyed by the mysterious manner of the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use dtrace to figure out what git it up to. Run this in another terminal and then run `git pull` as usual.

```
 $ sudo dtrace -qn 'syscall::execve:entry { printf("%s\n", copyinstr(arg0)); }'
 /usr/bin/uname
 /usr/libexec/git-core/git
```

... Cut ...

```
 /usr/libexec/git-core/git-pull
 /usr/libexec/git-core/ssh
 /usr/bin/ssh
```

Use `otool -L /usr/bin/ssh` to see if some library is missing.

But while writing this it think your problem might be on the server side. If you instead of my dtrace one-liner run `sudo newproc.d` while running `git pull` you will see something like this:

```
58694 64b  ssh me@example.com git-upload-pack 'some_repo.git'
```

Which indicates that the error might be from `git-upload-pack` when it is executed on the server side. So take a look at the dynamic libraries used by `git-upload-pack` on the server.

Try to run `ssh me@example.com 'ldd $(which git-upload-pack)'` and look for something fishy. Does `git-upload-pack` work from the shell?

Comment: is git-upload-pack not invoked server-side when using the ssh:// syntax? I thought me@foo.com:/example_repo.git was functionally equivalent to ssh://me@foo.com/example_repo.git If they do go through different routes can you offer any pointers as to why?

Comment: Don't have any pointers really why they differ, buy I did some testing and you are correct, git invokes ssh and git-upload-pack in the same way for the two syntaxes. Can you check if git connects to the server when you get the shared library error message? check the auth log for example (if you run some kind of unix). Updated my answer with a `ldd` suggestion too.